# Choosing Machine Learning algorithm for input values present in range

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear-regression, data-science

I am developing machine learning model for best suited crops based on soil   pH-Tolerance values. The input values which are present in range such as (5.0-6.0) and a multiple crop values lie in a single range value. such as

```
------      ---------  
Crop        pH-values 
------      ---------
Apple       (5.0-6.5)
Basil       (5.5-6.5)
Carrot      (5.5-7.0)
Cauliflower (5.5-7.5)
Chervil     (6.0-6.7)
Corn        (5.5-7.5.)
Cucumber    (5.5-7.0)
```

Kindly suggest which algorithm is best suited for the current problem.

Comment: So you are trying to predict on `Crop`?

Comment: yes based on pH

Comment: It's a classification problem then. You can use regression trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to predict the types of `Crop`, this is a classification problem. You could start by giving a look at some of the [classifiers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) in Scikit-Learn, which are quite simple to use. You can also get a good understanding on how to proceed from the examples in the documentation.

---

- *Here's a brief sketch on how to proceed*

Firstly you would have to do some preprocessing. You could begin with extracting the information from the lower on upper bounds from the ranges of the `pH-values`, you could do for example:

```
s = df['pH-values'].str.strip('(&)').str.split('-')
X_df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), columns = ['low','high'])
X_df['high'] = X_df.high.str.rstrip('.').astype(float)
X_df['low'] = X_df.low.astype(float)
print(X_df)

   low  high
0  5.0   6.5
1  5.5   6.5
2  5.5   7.0
3  5.5   7.5
4  6.0   6.7
5  5.5   7.5
6  5.5   7.0
```

The next step would be to feed the train and test data to whatever classifier you decide to work with ([RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) for example), and predict on some test data `X_test` obtained by splitting your data in `train` and test`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
y = df.Crop.values
X = X_df.values

# Split in train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

# Fit the classifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
model  = rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict using X_test
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Which will give you something as:

```
print(y_pred)
array(['Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Cauliflower'], dtype=object)
```

And finally check the accuracy you obtain with the defined model. For that you can use [`accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred, normalize=False)
```

Comment: excellent dear, let me try out , get back to you when I am done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did it help you? Don't forget to accept if so, thanks!